# Verify WiFi Settings Will Work via Command Line

Tags: wifi, ssh, remote, powershell

I'm remoting into a RPi Zero W using SSH. The RPi is connected to the internet via Ethernet cable. I want to set-up the WiFi at the current remote location and check that it will work when the Ethernet cable is disconnected.

I can set-up the WiFi via raspi-config or by directly editing the wpa_supplicant file. Is there a way to verify remotely that the WiFi will work once the Ethernet cable is unplugged?

If I run `iwgetid` I get nothing back, ostensibly because the wireless LAN is not currently being used. The command `iwconfig` gives me:

```
lo     no wireless extensions.
eth0   no wireless extensions.
wlan0  IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
       Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated
       Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
       Power Management:on
```

If I run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` I can see the network I want to connect to. Is there any way to test it while plugged into Ethernet?

OS is Raspbian installed via NOOBS v. 2.8.1. I did verify the RPi can connect to the internet over WiFi at my location before shipping it off to the current remote location.

Comment: you can use ping with a specific interface while still connected via ethernet so if it does not work you still maintain connectivity.

Comment: I'm unsure what you want to setup. You have a wired ethernet connection to your router and want a second connection with wifi to it that will be used without reboot if the wired connection is disconnected. Is it this what you want?

Comment: Or should there run an access point on the RasPi? Then you have already given the answer. Executing `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` on another device with wifi shows you the access point if running. For my understanding it doesn't matter if the ethernet cable is plugged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup `/etc/network/interfaces` as in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
then you can see if it has connected (and the IP) with `ip a`.

`route -vn` will show if there is an entry in the routing table (and the metric).
Both `eth0` and `wlan0` should have entries.